# Checking the solution to $2yy'=x(y')^2+4x,\ y(1)=-2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> I have to find a particular solution to the following differential equation:
>   $$
> 2yy'=x(y')^2+4x,\ y(1)=-2
> $$

I decided to substitute the values $x=1$ and $y=-2$ into the given equations. So, I got:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&-4y'=(y')^2+4\iff(y'+2)^2=0\iff y'=-2\iff y=-2x+C\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow [\text{Substitute $y$ into the initial diff. eq.}]\Rightarrow (-4x+2C)(-2)=4x+4x\Rightarrow C=0\\
&\text{Answer: } y=-2x
\end{aligned}
$$
But I'm not sure of my solution. Could anyone check it please?

Comment: This isn't quite right - you've only shown that $y'(1) =-2$, which does not imply $y'(x) = -2x + C$

Comment: Could you provide the correct solution then, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint.

Solve for $y'$ giving

$$
y'=\frac 1x\left(y\pm\sqrt{y^2-4x^2}\right)
$$

or

$$
y' = \frac yx\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac yx\right)^2-4}
$$

and now making

$$
z = \frac yx
$$

we have

$$
z'=\pm \frac 1x\sqrt{z^2-4}
$$

which is separable.

NOTE

$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\pm\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^2-4}}
$$

Comment: that's .... awesome.+1

Comment: Thank you for the solution! May I ask you to check the final result? It is either $x=C\left(\frac{y}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}-4}\right)\ \ \left(C=-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ or $x=C/\left(\frac{y}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}-4}\right)\ \ (C=-2)$.

Comment: According to my calculations, one of the solutions gives $$y = \frac{1}{C_0}+C_0 x^2$$

Comment: I got it. Thank you!